# How to get secure hashing software?

Tags: hash

I am searching for an open source hash calculator that I can download to verify my Tails .iso image, but I also want to be able to to calculate some password hashes with a sha512 hash (which is why I don't trust online hashing websites since they can steal the password and the corresponding hash in their database, I think).

I haven't been able to find one, so is there any that you would recommend?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, but maybe checkout https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com . Make sure you read their help center for how to ask a good question, it's not super clear what you are looking for. I also suspect most *nix software come with everything you need.

Comment: Oh yes... The competition among SHA-calculating software vendors is so fierce and the software evolves so fast that it's indeed a dreadful software recommendation request. And OP should instead specify the purpose. For example that it's for verifying a downloaded .iso image or hashing passwords locally. Oh, wait, OP did that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of open source methods for creating sha512 hashes.

- There is a mkpassword libary as mentioned in [this article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow) for Linux:

  ```
  mkpasswd  -m sha-512 -S saltsalt -s <<< YourPass
  ```
- Using Python and the crypt library as stated in [another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/330069/how-to-create-an-sha-512-hashed-password-for-shadow):

  ```
  python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("test", "$6$random_salt")
  ```